# Run .exe files on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos

I know it is possible to run windows files on Mac using cider or Wine, I have CrossOver, but I am totally confused how to do it. *What would be the **simplest working way** to run a windows .exe file on a Mac?* This pertains to one that has *no* GUI, just function.

Comment: i think with no gui you mean command line based Application - so to run a .exe inside of a Terminal i would recommend to use mono (it's a c#/c++ crossplattform framework incl. Devtools to programm Windows Applications on Linux and Mac. And by the simple fact that a developer also needs to test the Application you can also use mono to just run a .exe

Answer (score 3):

Running something like a command-line Windows application on a Mac is, unfortunately, not really possible. Even the most seamlessly integrated solutions (like CrossOver) just create a small Windows environment that the application runs in; you don't get access to things like the output stream or the file system of the application, and I don't think that it has much--if any--access to the host file system.

Beyond that, you'll have to be more specific as to what you're exactly trying to do; there may be options for a specific case, but there's no general solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Parallels to run a Windows environment on your Mac, then this is scriptable via AppleScript and you can run WIndows programs from within Mac OS X via AppleScript. You can also generate the equivalent AppleScript commands from the command line (`man osascript`) or from an Objective-C program if you want to. For an example of how to do this see: http://initapp.com/2006/12/07/start-windows-apps-from-your-osx-doc-parallels-3036/

Answer (score 0):

Install **Wine** on Mac OS X.

References: [01](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/), [02](http://davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/), [03](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX)